# How to make .command file execute at its location

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, automation

When you execute a .command file it is not at the location where the file resides. You can place a .command file anywhere with the command `pwd` in it, and it will always print your Users folder.

I need the file to execute at its location because I am trying to run `nodemon my/file.js` and currently it is looking for `Users/(myname)/my/file.js` which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always used the `$0` variable to find the directory the command is in and go there first.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change directory to be where the command is.
cd "$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" > /dev/null && pwd)"

# Print the working directory for example.
pwd
```

Comment: It should be noted that in any proper shell script, you should **always** make sure that `cd` actually succeeded.

Comment: `$0` will work if it's run from the Finder, but if it's run from the command line this might not work. As long as it's running under bash, `$BASH_SOURCE` is more reliable. See [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)